# ERD in Oracle Toad - is there a menu option

Tags: toad

Do any of you know how to view an ERD diagram in Toad for Oracle Professional 12.1.1.1? I have been told it is in Tool->ERD Diagram but I don't have a Tools menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's on the Database menu, Report submenu. ER Diagram.

Comment: Is there a view that I can see a diagram of the relationship between 2 tables?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. The ER Diagram does show tables and relationships graphically for easy viewing. If you add multiple tables and there are any relationships then lines will be drawn to connect the tables.